Town of Doppelgängers and the Protagonist Wearing a Spacesuit
A long time ago, almost surely no later than the year 1994, I saw a film in which a town was replaced with impostors, like Doppelgängers of some sort, maybe aliens.
The ending involved the protagonist walking around in a spacesuit for some reason. I'm not sure, but the impostors may have turned into mannequins under some circumstances.
IIRC there was a villainess who mocked the protagonist at some point, or otherwise talked at him in a discouraging manner.
IIRC there was was a scene where the protagonist's family (children?) were trapped by some force under a spotlight surrounded by darkness, and the protagonist had to take off the spacesuit to somehow symbolise recognising his family to break through.
What film might that be?

Did you see it in the theatre or on tv (was it a new movie at the time you saw it). Color or B/W? In what country did you see it?

@ArlettaS On either TV or VHS. In the Republic of Seychelles. I was a kid, I'm not entirely sure if it was in colour. I think there was a bit of a red hue in some scenes, but I've had my memory/imagination play tricks on me in that era with a B&W TV before (and I'm not even sure when we switched to a colour TV).

Any chance you're thinking of one of the adaptations of "Mars is Heaven" from Ray Bradbury's Martian Chronicles? It features astronauts landing on Mars, only to find an American small town, populated by long-passed members of the astronauts' families.
It was adapted on an episode of The Twilight Zone, and as part of the NBC mini-series of the book in 1980. There's a chance some of the sequences you're thinking of came from other parts of the series?

Took a look at it through Youbute (searching for Twilight Zone Mars is Heaven). Doesn't seem to be the one, but thank you, this was a good attempt that had good potential.
